# unexpected result while working with array

Tags: c

sir i am a new programmer.So i am facing some new problems which I really need to solve. Like I write a code

```
#include<stdio.h>
 main(){
  int ara[] ={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},i,temp,j; 
  for(i=0,j=9;i<10;i++,j--){ 
      ara[i]=ara[j];
      printf("%d\n",ara[i]); } 
    }
```

I thought the result would be 100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10 but the result is not like this...Would anyone please tell me why the result shows 100,90,80,70,60,60,70,80,90,100

Comment: Perhaps first explain why you thought the result would be "100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10" with code changing `ara[]` with  `ara[i]=ara[j];`?  Perhaps try this with `int ara[] ={1,2,3,4}`?

Comment: @chux I totally missread the question, I thought OP said that was the result and they were expecting it to be the actual result, I thought, *"That makes no sense"*

Comment: Step through the code with your debugger, watching the values at each step.  All will become clear.

Comment: `int ara_r[10];`..`ara_r[i]=ara[j];printf("%d\n",ara_r[i]);`

Comment: sir because I was thinking that ara[j]=100 which is going to ara[i] which is index[0]...Then I am reducing the j and increasing the i..so ara[j]=90 will go to the ara[i] which is index[1].And I am printing the index[i] values.Was there any logical problem sir?

Comment: Consider that `arr[0]=10` happened first in initialization and then `arr[0]` was assigned the value 100 with `ara[i]=ara[j];`.  That `10` is lost.  it is no longer in the array.  So code will not print out `.... 40,30,20,10`.  At the end of the first loop iteration, the array is 100, 20, 30, ..., 90, 100. After the 2nd it is 100, 90, 30, ..., 90, 100. (the 20 is lost)

Comment: maybe You want like [this](https://ideone.com/hLOVrr)

Comment: @chux sir,I got it.Now it make sense.Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 3):

After printing value 60, i.e. half of the array when you try to access elements further, actually you will access those elements which are of the locations after mid of the array. because you are assigning them using ara[i] = ara[j]..so you will end up with repetition after half of array.
As:-

```
ara[0] = ara[9]
ara[1] = ara[8]
ara[2] = ara[7]
ara[3] = ara[6]
ara[4] = ara[5]
ara[5] = ara[4]
```

The simplest solution may be creating a temporary array:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
 main(){
  int ara[] ={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},i,temp[10],j; 
  for(i = 9, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++){ 
      temp[j]=ara[i];
   } 
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      printf("%d\n", temp[i]);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in this code?

> reversing an array

Why are you printing 100,90,80,70,60,50,60,70,...

> because when you reach the 6th one (ara[4]), you've already swapped it with 4th one (ara[6])

Answer (score 1):

You need to save in the temporary variable the value which is written first

Some examples

```
char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char tmp;
    int len;

    if (str != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen(str);
        for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
        {
            tmp = *(str + i);
            *(str + i) = *(str + len - i - 1);
            *(str + len - i - 1) = tmp;

        }
    }
    return str;
}

int *reverseints(int *data, size_t size)
{
    int tmp;

    if (data != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
        {
            tmp = *(data + i);
            *(data + i) = *(data + size - i - 1);
            *(data + size - i - 1) = tmp;

        }
    }
    return data;
}
```